# Align text inside span to top of container

Tags: html, css, text, vertical-alignment

Is there a way to have the text start AT THE VERY TOP BORDER of its span?

In here you can see there's a little “padding” due to the line-height.
Is there a way to do it?

```css
.name {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.25;
  font-size: 45px;
}
.firstname {
  display: block;
  background: #FFAACC;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="ej ej1">
    <span class="name">
      <span class="firstname">Something Name</span>
    <span class="username">
        @somthig-name
        </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "little “padding” due to the line-height."
Here's my take at the puzzle.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.name {
  margin-top:-0.9rem;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.25;
  font-size: 45px;
}
.firstname {
  display: block;
  background: #FFAACC;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
      <div class="ej ej1">
        <span class="name">
          <span class="firstname">Something Name</span>
        <span class="username">
            @somthig-name
            </span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what your asking for is only possible if you change line-height for each html tag manually. And this is the exact thing you are looking for I think so..

```css
.name {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 33px;
  font-size: 45px;
}
.firstname {
  display: block;
  background: #FFAACC;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<body style="margin:0px;">
<div>
  <div class="ej ej1">
    <span class="name">
      <span class="firstname">Something Name</span>
    <span class="username">
        @somthig-name
        </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that `<body>` has a margin of 8px...
try this

```css
.name {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.25;
  font-size: 45px;
}
.firstname {
  display: block;
  background: #FFAACC;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body style="margin:0px;">
<div>
  <div class="ej ej1">
    <span class="name">
      <span class="firstname">Something Name</span>
    <span class="username">
        @somthig-name
        </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Otherwirse if you were talking about the text itself, I believe that has to do with the font itself, which you would have to create a font with absolutely no whitespace above the characters.